# Revert pushed branch to previous commit and erase commits after that

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working on a Git project with another developer. He accidentally committed something and pushed it, but we don't want it there.

We are trying to find a way to hard reset the branch back to a previous commit, which will then destroy the history after that commit so it's like we just made the last good commit.

All we can find is 'safe' ways to revert, but we actually want to know if there is a completely destructive way to remove the pushed commits and revert back to a previous one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We are trying to find a way to hard reset the branch back to a previous commit...

That would be `git reset --hard <commit>`.  This will discard all history since `<commit>`.  You will probably need to use `git push --force` to update the remote repository with these changes.

Comment: ... and all developers will want to delete their local copies of the branch and pull in the new version.

Comment: Or just `git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master` (assuming the `master` branch).

Comment: Even though OP seems aware of the destructiveness of this, to the readers: please do not do this at home (i.e. master).

Comment: Ah, thanks. It was the forced push we needed, I think.